# i need help display data in a two column div in laravel blade file

Tags: laravel

Im having trouble displaying data in a two column div in laravel using bootstrap. The content of the other div is going below the other for some reason. Heres the code.

```
@extends('layouts.app')
@section('content')
<!--twitch client id!-- vzq62rzb1bbh0d1ebtp5pcx70ysvva!-->
<h1>Hello {{user->user_name}}</h1>

<body background = "img/cool_background.png">

    <div class = "container">

        <div class = "col-md-3">

                <div id = "firstNewsCard" class = "row wow fadeInLeft">

        </div>

        <div class = "c0l-md-9">

            <!--the other column div!-->

        </div>

     </div>

</body>

@endsection
```

Comment: `class = "c0l-md-9"` should be `class = "col-md-9"`.

Answer (score 0):

you made a little mistake, '0' instead of 'o'

```
  <div class = "c0l-md-9">  -->  `  <div class = "col-md-9">`
```

good luck

Answer (score 0):

As bootstrap doc suggests, you should use an element with class="row" to wrap all inner col-x-y classed elements (with "x" being xs, sm, md or lg and "y" usually summing 12, could be less but not more), like:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-3">

        </div>
        <div class="col-md-9">

        </div>
    </div>

</div>
```